# load cell produces an average weight that is far from actual weight

Tags: c++, arduino

So I'm using an HX711 Load Cell Amplifier and a 1kg load cell. I wanted to get the average of 30 samples and determine the size of the egg based on its weight. What happens is the average weight is so much less than the true weight of the object I'm placing on the load cell, like the object is 205 grams and the average weight the serial monitor prints is 33.38

```
//------------------HEADERS------------------
#include <HX711_ADC.h>
#if defined(ESP8266)|| defined(ESP32) || defined(AVR)
#include <EEPROM.h>
#endif

//------------------CONSTANTS------------------
#define ST_CALIB 0
#define ST_EGGHERE 1
#define ST_ISEGG 2
#define ST_GETWEIGHT 3
#define ST_GETCOLOR 4

//Pins for Color sensor
#define S0 4
#define S1 5
#define S2 7
#define S3 6
#define sensorOut 8

//Constants for color sensor
const int ORANGE_RED_MIN = 13000;
const int ORANGE_RED_MAX = 14000;
const int ORANGE_GREEN_MIN = 14000;
const int ORANGE_GREEN_MAX = 15000;
const int ORANGE_BLUE_MIN = 20000;
const int ORANGE_BLUE_MAX = 21000;

//Constants for Calibration Value
const int calVal_eepromAdress = 0;
unsigned long t = 0 ;

//-----LOADCELL STUFF----
#define NUM_SAMPLES_WEIGHT 20
//Pins for Load cell
const int HX711_dout = 4; //mcu > HX711 dout pin
const int HX711_sck = 5; //mcu > HX711 sck pin

//------------------GLOBAL VARIABLES-------------
//Actual Load cell object
HX711_ADC LoadCell(HX711_dout, HX711_sck);

//setting states
int currState = 0;
int nextState = 0;

//Variables for color sensor
int red = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;

//Variables for IR Sensor
bool egg = false;
int initialReadingsCounter = 0;

//Declaring Utility Functions
void CheckEgg();
void check_Weight_Size();
void calibrate();


//------------------SETUP------------------
void setup() {

  //Setting Pins for IR Sensor
  pinMode(3,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(57600);

  // Setting the outputs
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);
  
  // Setting the sensorOut as an input
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);
  
  // Setting frequency scaling to 20% 
  digitalWrite(S0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S1, LOW);

  // Initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(57600); 

  Serial.begin(57600); 
  delay(100);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting...");

  LoadCell.setGain(32);
  LoadCell.begin();
  //LoadCell.setReverseOutput(); //uncomment to turn a negative output value to positive
  float calibrationValue; // calibration value (see example file "Calibration.ino")
  calibrationValue = 696.0; // uncomment this if you want to set the calibration value in the sketch

#if defined(ESP8266)|| defined(ESP32)
  //EEPROM.begin(512); // uncomment this if you use ESP8266/ESP32 and want to fetch the calibration value from eeprom
#endif
  EEPROM.get(calVal_eepromAdress, calibrationValue); // uncomment this if you want to fetch the calibration value from eeprom

  unsigned long stabilizingtime = 2000; // preciscion right after power-up can be improved by adding a few seconds of stabilizing time
  boolean _tare = false; //set this to false if you don't want tare to be performed in the next step
  LoadCell.start(stabilizingtime, _tare);
  if (LoadCell.getTareTimeoutFlag()) {
    Serial.println("Timeout, check MCU>HX711 wiring and pin designations");
    while (1);
  }
  else {
    LoadCell.setCalFactor(calibrationValue); // set calibration value (float)
    Serial.println("Startup is complete");
  }
}

//------------------MAIN LOOP------------------
void loop() {

  switch (currState) {
    case ST_CALIB: {
      calibrate();
      nextState = ST_EGGHERE;
      break;
    }
    case ST_EGGHERE: {
    if (egg != true){
       CheckEgg();
      nextState = ST_EGGHERE;
    }
    else {
      nextState = ST_ISEGG;
    }
    break;
    }
    case ST_ISEGG: {
      delay(1000);
      float weight = readLoadCell();

      //Check Weight
      if(weight < 10) {
        Serial.println("No Egg");
        nextState = ST_ISEGG;
      }
      else {
        nextState = ST_GETWEIGHT;
        Serial.println("Doing this");
      }
    break;
    }
    case ST_GETWEIGHT:
      Serial.println("SENSING WEIGHT");
      //Read weight
      float weight = readLoadCell();
      //Check weight
      check_Weight_Size(weight);
      nextState = ST_GETCOLOR;
      break;
    case ST_GETCOLOR:
      Serial.println("SENSING COLOR");
      nextState = ST_GETWEIGHT;
      break;
  }

  currState = nextState;
  delay(10);
}

//------------------UTILITY FUNCTIONS------------------
float readLoadCell() {
  float sumWeight = 0;
  float aveWeight = 0;
  float initialWeight = 0;
  bool newDataReady = false;

  //Read values multiple times
  for(int i = NUM_SAMPLES_WEIGHT; i > 0; i-- ){
    //Wait and keep checking if data is ready 
    while(!newDataReady){
      delay(10000);
      // check for new data/start next conversion:
      if (LoadCell.update()){
        newDataReady = true;
        delay(10000);
      }
    }
    sumWeight += LoadCell.getData();
    }
  
  // Get average of all measured weight
  aveWeight = sumWeight/NUM_SAMPLES_WEIGHT;
  return aveWeight;
}

void check_Weight_Size(float weight){
  
  // Check different weight ranges and perform actions accordingly
    if (weight >= 70) {
        Serial.println(weight);
        Serial.println("Jumbo");
      } else if (weight >= 65.0 && weight < 69.9) {
        Serial.println(weight);
        Serial.println("Extra Large");
      } else if (weight >= 60.0 && weight < 64.9) {
        Serial.println(weight);
        Serial.println("Large");
      }else if (weight >= 55.0 && weight < 59.9) {
        Serial.println(weight);
        Serial.println("Medium");
      }else if (weight >= 50.0 && weight < 54.9) {
        Serial.println(weight);
        Serial.println("Small");
      }else if (weight >= 40.0 && weight < 49.9) {
        Serial.println("Peewee");
      }else if (weight < 44.9) {
        Serial.println(weight);
        Serial.println("Reject");
      }   
}

void CheckEgg() {
  if (digitalRead(3) == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println("Egg Not Detected");
    egg = false;
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Egg Detected");
    egg = true;
  }
}

void calibrate() {
  Serial.println("*");
  Serial.println("Start calibration:");
  Serial.println("Place the load cell an a level stable surface.");
  Serial.println("Remove any load applied to the load cell.");
  Serial.println("Send 't' from serial monitor to set the tare offset.");

  boolean _resume = false;
  while (_resume == false) {
    LoadCell.update();
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char inByte = Serial.read();
        if (inByte == 't') LoadCell.tareNoDelay();
      }
    }
    if (LoadCell.getTareStatus() == true) {
      Serial.println("Tare complete");
      _resume = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: multiply the weight in the serial monitor by `6.1414`, there is a `calibrationValue` variable for that.